# Pylint throwing configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError:

Tags: python, pylint

I ma testing a python file using pylint

Code is below

```
""" Testing the file inside the content"""
import json

file = r'test.txt'
with open(file,'r') as fr:
    fd = fr.read()
    print (fd)
```

Below is the command to test

```
pylint code.py
```

Error is below

```
raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'C:\\Users\\ayshewew\\.pylintrc', line: 2
'import json\n'
```

I have executed above code in jupyter notebook and working fine

My pylint is the latest version

Comment: I get something else when running your code on Windows 10 python 2.7.17 and pylint 1.9.5, get  :  Module code
C:  7, 0: Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword (superfluous-parens)
W:  4, 0: Redefining built-in 'file' (redefined-builtin)
C:  4, 0: Constant name "file" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
C:  6, 4: Constant name "fd" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
W:  2, 0: Unused import json (unused-import)

Comment: Try to update all your modules update pylint and configparser and try again

Comment: Show the content of the `C:\\Users\\ayshewew\\.pylintrc` file. As clearly indicated in the error message it seems to contain `import json` on the second line, which seems very surprising to find in this kind of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried

`python -m pylint code.py` got the output

working